# HTML video tag is not working on safari browser

Tags: javascript, web, safari, blazor, html5-video

video is not playing in safari browser although it's working fine in chrome is there any issue with video tag or am i missing something. i know i have given two different resources for video but even after giving same resources it was not working fine.
Here is my code.

```
<video controls muted playsinline loop preload>
 <source src="/css/images/hero-video-webm" type="video/webm">
 <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv" type="video/ogg">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I got it working by adding the src as attribute of the video tag itself (<video ... src='...'/>) whether this is ideal or not, I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

here's what worked for me: (im using **nextjs** **13.4**)

```
<video
      ref={videoRef}
      playsInline={true}
      muted={true}
      autoPlay={true}
      loop={true}
      controls={false}
      preload="auto"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      className="pointer-events-none h-full w-full select-none overflow-hidden object-cover"
    >
     <source src="/BackgroundVideo.webm#t=0.001" type="video/webm" />
     <source src="/BackgroundVideo.mp4#t=0.001" type="video/mp4" />
```

i believe it was the extra source that i added (mp4) what got it to work.

Answer (score -1):

ok so i myself found out the solution before then i thought i should post it on this helping community and platform we can simply autoplay our video by using javascript in blazor.

only will not be enough for autoplay so just add a class on video tag and pass it with `InvokeVoidAsync` method which is invoking your javascript function which js function will take that class as a parameter and call .play() method. Here i am mentioning both blazor and js code.

blazor file

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS;

<video class="responsive-video video-play" loop>
    <source src="/images/landing/hero-video-mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="/images/landing/hero-video-webm.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>

@code {

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("window.playVideo", "video-play");
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

js file

```
window.playVideo = function (videoPlay) {
    var videos = document.getElementsByClassName(videoPlay);
    for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        videos[i].muted = true;
        videos[i].play();
    }
}
```

i had multiple videos that must be played as soon as page loads that why i invoked js method inside OnAfterRender and iterated on video.